# how to print 3 numbers greater than a specific number of a list in python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have written the following code which will ask for a number from the user and check the number in the list if they are greater than the user input, then it will print the next 3 numbers. I just don't understand how to implement the condition so that it prints the next 3 numbers, not all!

```py
def main():
    number_list = [630,1015,1415,1620,1720,2000]
    a=int(input("Enter the time (as an integer):"))
    for i in number_list:
        if(i>=a):
            print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please update your question with an example input and the expected output.

Comment: careful, in python uppercase / lowercase matters. `i` is not the same as `I`

Comment: @quamrana Enter the time (as an integer): 1000
The next buses leave:
1015
1415
1620                                         Enter the time (as an integer): 1800
The next buses leave:
2000
630
1015 These two are expected outputs

Answer (score 2):

I would first find the index of the first value that meets your condition (element greater than or equal to the inputted value):

```py
user_input = int(input("Enter the time (as an integer):"))
desired_index = None
for index, val in enumerate(number_list):
    if val >= user_input:
        desired_index = index
        break
```

Then to print the three values including and after that position:

```py
    print(number_list[desired_index:desired_index + 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the list is sorted, you can use the built-in `bisect` module to find the position where the input number fits into the list. Then it's easy to print the next three numbers from the list (if there are that many):

```py
import bisect

number_list = [630, 1015, 1415, 1620, 1720, 2000]
a = int(input("Enter the time (as an integer):"))

index = bisect.bisect(number_list, a)
print(number_list[index:(index + 3)])
```

E.g. for input `1200` this prints `[1415, 1620, 1720]` .

Comment: I am not allowed to import any library for this problem, just the lists

Comment: In that case I would do it as user9596600 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to be:

```
def main():
    number_list = [630,1015,1415,1620,1720,2000]
    a=int(input("Enter the time (as an integer):"))
    i=0
    for n in number_list:
        if(n>=a):
            print(n)
            i+=1
            if i==3:break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now run the code and see the output..

```
Enter the time (as an integer):1015
1015
1415
1620
>>>
```

If you want to ensure that `number_list` is sorted, then use this sort method..

```
number_list.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is sorted, you should use binary search (e.g. bisect) otherwise you can print the first 3 elements of a filtered list:

```
print(*[n for n in number_list if n>a][:3])
```

for a more basic approach, you can keep track of how many numbers you've printed so far using a variable that you increase by one after printing a number and use that print counter in the condition to decide to print:

```
printed = 0                 # count of numbers printed so far
for n in number_list:
    if printed<3 and n>a:   # only print first 3 that are eligible
        print(n)
        printed += 1        # track number of numbers printed
```